# R - any function for multiple different-sized resampling

Tags: r

Is there any function can solve this kind of different-sized random resampling problem? For example, given a vector, `data = c('a','a','b','c','d','e')`. I want to randomly resample this vector into 3 groups with different sizes 1 ,3 ,2 respectively. Like

```
input:  samplefunc(data,size = c(1,3,2)) 
output: c('a')  c('a','d','e')  c('b','c')
```

I only found this "sample" function, but it is only for one size sample:

```
sample(x, size, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)
size: a non-negative integer giving the number of items to choose.
```

Since I have to divide the data into many groups(not just 3), if there is an existed function can do that, it will be much easier without the for-loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily write your own function using, say, `lapply`, which would return a `list` of your samples:

```
samplefunc <- function(vec, size, ...) lapply(size, function(x) sample(vec, x, ...))
```

Usage would be as you imagined:

```
samplefunc(data, c(1, 3, 2))
```

---

As @thelatemail suggests, if you wanted to do sampling without replacement, you can try defining `samplefunc` as:

```
samplefunc <- function(vec, size) {
  temp <- split(vec, sample(rep(size, size)))
  temp[match(names(temp), as.character(size))]
}
```

Comment: This would be sampling with replacement, which I assume OP probably wants if they are doing resampling stats. You could do `samplefunc <- function(x, size) split(x, sample(rep(seq_along(size), size)))` or something similar if it was to sample without replacement.

Comment: @thelatemail, True. If you don't mind, I'll edit your suggestion in as an alternative. I hadn't noticed that their "size" added up to `length(data)`.

Comment: I don't mind - you can buy me a beer if i'm ever in Chennai as payment :-)

Comment: @thelatemail, It's pretty soggy here, so you may want to delay any visit you're planning. But otherwise, please do come over :-)

Comment: Yes, as @thelatemail said, it should be without replacement. Sorry I didn't say clearly. The final answer is what I want, you guys awesome! THX~